# Google Drive API: Is there "Invited as" field?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using JavaScript to get the permissions of my shared folder using the follow code:

```
gapi.client.drive.permissions.list({
   'fileId': fileID,
   'fields': '*'
});
```

Returns

```
{
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "121212321331323321313",
   "type": "user",
   "emailAddress": "bar.foo@gmail.com",
   "role": "reader",
   "displayName": "Foo Bar",
   "deleted": false,
   "expirationTime": "2018-03-23T02:59:59.000Z",
},
```

My issue is: 
I shared my folder with not gmail domains. Google sends a invitation to acept , then, requires a login with G Suite accounts to share, and when it happens, another user is add at permissions list. This user when MouseHover displays this information:

[image]

[Google Drive permissions Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions)

Are there any ways to get this information (invited as) ? (preferably via API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time that data is not available.  Even doing a [permissions .get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/get) returns the full [permission resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource) does not contain that information.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "id": string,
  "type": string,
  "emailAddress": string,
  "domain": string,
  "role": string,
  "allowFileDiscovery": boolean,
  "displayName": string,
  "photoLink": string,
  "expirationTime": datetime,
  "teamDrivePermissionDetails": [
    {
      "teamDrivePermissionType": string,
      "role": string,
      "inheritedFrom": string,
      "inherited": boolean
    }
  ],
  "deleted": boolean
}
```

You might want to consider adding this as a feature request.  [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B)